# JavaFX: Why doesn't the setContent method of SwingNode with a JComponent parameter accept a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx-8, java-8

I have the following code:

```
private void launchSingleRecordWindow() {
    SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    MainStageController.setContent(new AnchorPane(swingNode));
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(selectedWebcam);
            swingNode.setContent(webcamPanel);
        }
    });
}
```

But to my surprise the string `swingNode.setContent(webcamPanel);` isn't correct.

IntelliJ IDEA says:

> `java: incompatible types: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be converted to javax.swing.JComponent`.

I've tried to make separate class, but it works only when it is a subclass of `JComponent`, but not for its subclasses, such as `JFrame` or `JPanel`. What is wrong?

Comment: So, what's a `SwingNode`?  And what's the EXACT signature for its `setContent(...)`?

Comment: @splungebob `SwingNode` is a class of JavaFX8. Look here: [link](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/index.html?javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I must've missed the javafx tags when I first replied.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: a JPanel is a JComponent - either your imports are incorrect or you are not running the code you think you are running...

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that a `JFrame` is not a `JComponent`.  Guess what?  It's right.

See for yourself: [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's my mistake... But I've done it with JPanel - the result is the same.

Comment: Then there's more to the story that you're not telling. Any method signature with a `JComponent` as a param will also accept a `JPanel`, or subclass of `JPanel`.  Always.

Comment: @Eugene there's must be something wrong with your code, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` is not a `JComponent` subclass, it's a `Component` subclass, so it can't be converted to `JComponent`

Answer (score 0):

The error is strange:

```
java: incompatible types: javax.swing.JPanel cannot be converted to javax.swing.JComponent
```

Because ... A JPanel is a JComponent:

```
Class JPanel
java.lang.Object
   java.awt.Component
      java.awt.Container
         javax.swing.JComponent
            javax.swing.JPanel
```

And a SwingNode does accept a JComponent:

```
public void setContent(javax.swing.JComponent content)
```

So ... it should work to pass a JPanel to a SwingNode::setContent

**Check your code or compile in verbose mode and see if the error is what you think it is!**